# How to get the input cursor position in Winforms WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

We use the Winforms WebBrowser Control as simple editor.

Is there a way to get the position (character position in text) of the input cursor in the text. (Not in the input bar)

**What do I need?**
I need the implementation of `SelectionStart` in the WebBrowser control. (Where is the input cursor)

**Why do I need this?**
Since the RichtText control does not support properly links with alternative link text, we need the WebBrowser control as alternative editor.

**Edit**

My final goal is to retrieve the link data (such as "example.com") at the position where the cursor is located when the cursor is placed over a link without the user clicking on the link. In my case, there is no real link, but metadata used within the program logic. (Example: am12rp12300rt147600) instead of a real link like the mentioned "example.com"

Comment: Sorry, you meant the position of the input cursor in the url bar?

Comment: @AlexandreCastro no, in the text. I edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain why would you need this? I am trying to figure out some other way of solving your problem.

Comment: @AlexandreCastro I edited my post

Comment: @marsh-wiggle TextBox has two property/methods `SelectionStart` and `GetCharIndex`, they are different. Which one of them you are trying to implement for the editable DIV element?

Comment: @RezaAghaei This question is about an editable WebBrowser. In TextBox / RichText SelectionStart and GetCharIndex work as expected. There we have problems with the links. So we are looking for an alternative

Comment: I see, I'm asking which feature you are looking for? Equivalent of which method you are going to implement in editable browser? In fact it's not quite clear what you are asking. Cursor, caret, position and char index are different things.

Comment: @RezaAghaei We need links with an alternative link text. This works in RichText but the link-click-event doesn't fire when the linktext and the link destination differ.

Comment: I'm not asking about the reason of using a WebBrowser instead of a RichTextBox, you already have described it. I'm asking you to clarify the question. Read my previous comment again. It's not clear what you are asking. You may want to add some illustration or more description.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes, you are right, its misleading. I need to ask on monday my colleague what he needs. In this case I am not the programmer. Thanks!

Comment: @RezaAghaei I edited the question

Comment: Is your final goal inserting a link for selected text, for example let's say "example" is selected and you want to convert it to a link to "example.com", using `<a href="example.com">example</example>`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I edited the question; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get input cursor position via Javascript.

1. Javascript on your html file:

```
function insertAtCursor(myValue) {
    //IE support
    if (document.selection) {        
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = myValue;     
    }       
}
```

2. Insert text at cursor

```
Dim result As String = WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("insertAtCursor", New [Object]() {"TEST"})
```

3. Download source code from my blog

[Source code insert text at cursor (VB.NET)](https://www.tummosoftware.com/2019/03/how-to-get-input-cursor-position.html)

Comment: You need to add disclosure when linking your own websites. See [how not to be a spammer](/help/promotion)

Comment: How can I avoid false results if the text appears multiple times?